# PySyft AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'federate' while reading data from csv

Tags: dataframe, pytorch, federated-learning, pysyft

I am trying to implement that pysyft code for federated learing for my csv data . The tutorial i am following is this https://github.com/bt-s/Split-Learning-and-Federated-Learning/blob/master/src/federated_learning.py  they used torch library FMNIST data which is iamge . I am having difficulty in customizing this code for my csv data.

This is error i am getting

> File "C:/user/python/PCA/federated_learning.py", line 175, in 
> train_loader = sy.FederatedDataLoader(train_set, transform=data_transformer.federate(workers), train=True,
> batch_size=args.batch_size, shuffle=True,  **kwargs) AttributeError:
> 'Compose' object has no attribute 'federate

```
# Pysyft needs to be hooked to PyTorch to enable its features
    hook = sy.TorchHook(torch)

    # Define the workers
    alfa    = sy.VirtualWorker(hook, id="alfa")
    bravo   = sy.VirtualWorker(hook, id="bravo")
    workers = (alfa, bravo)

    device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
    device = torch.device(device)
    kwargs = {'num_workers': 1, 'pin_memory': True} if device=="cuda" else {}

    # Specify required data transformation
    data_transformer = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,))
    ])

    import pandas as pd
    print("Loading CSV...")
    test_set = pd.read_csv("C:/user/python/PCA/data/test.csv", encoding = "UTF-8")
    train_set = pd.read_csv("C:/user/python/PCA/data/train.csv", encoding = "UTF-8")
    train_loader = sy.FederatedDataLoader(train_set, transform=data_transformer.federate(workers), train=True, batch_size=args.batch_size, shuffle=True,  **kwargs)
    test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_set, transform=data_transformer, train=False, batch_size=args.batch_size, shuffle=True,  **kwargs)
```

Comment: This `data_transformer.federate(workers)` is the problem. The implementation [here](https://github.com/bt-s/Split-Learning-and-Federated-Learning/blob/master/src/federated_learning.py#L185) called `federate` over the `datasets.FashionMNIST` not the `Compose`

Comment: yeah i know  this line is causing the problem but i am not able to resolve it

Comment: One way to make it runs is remove `.federate(workers)` but the question is why do you want it in the first place? Since I don't remember `torchvision.Dataset` has `.federate` method.

Comment: you can see in the tutorial link that they expalined workers and use .federate(workers) other way is to define every worker by name there .federate((alice, bob))  like in this tutorial https://www.kaggle.com/vedanthpadigelwar/federated-learning-and-privacy-preservation

Comment: it probably need torchvision 0.5.0 and I don't have that.

Comment: What I can suggest is, it has to be `train_set.federate(workers)` not the `data_transformer`

Comment: Both `transform=data_transforme` and `train=False` have to be in the `Dataset`. And since `pd.Dataframe` isn't a `Dataset` object so you'll have to write a new one.

Comment: already tried this one train_loader = sy.FederatedDataLoader(train_set.federate(workers), batch_size=args.batch_size, shuffle=True,  **kwargs)  it gives this error AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'federate'

Comment: Yup, as I said `pd.DataFrame` isn't a `Dataset`. You have to write a custom dataset or maybe look for something like "pytorch pandas Dataset"

Comment: i didnt get you .. why i need to write custom dataset or need pytorch dataset i am reading my data from csv file